# Как преобразовать connect в переменную PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qcombobox

Мне нужно при изменении выбора элемента `comboBox` получить значение выбранного элемента, но возникает проблема в коде: при `print(test)` выводит:

`<PyQt5.QtCore.QMetaObject.Connection object at 0x000001B852852DC0>`.

Каким образом мне забрать результат из функции `get_Format` без использования глобальных переменных, выгрузки информации (по типу sql)?

```
...
test = self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.get_Format)

def get_Format(self):
    comboBox1_Text = self.comboBox.currentText()
    return comboBox1_Text
...
```

Comment: Как вы себе представляете себе ЭТО использовать, даже если гипотетически предположить что такое может работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QComboBox, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        myList = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3',]
        self.current_text = 'item 1'
    
        comboBox = QComboBox()
        comboBox.addItems(myList)
        comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_currentTextChanged)
        
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(comboBox, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def on_currentTextChanged(self, text):
        self.current_text = text
        print(self.current_text)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ТрейдерХулионер что не так?

Comment: сделал по твоему примеру, результатом доволен, спасибо тебе

Comment: @ТрейдерХулионер пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour